# Is this an EF Core bug or an I doing it wrong to update one entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core together with the repository pattern. To help me out, I coded one base repository with the basic CRUD methods. The update method is as follows:

```
public void Update(TEntity entity)
{
    var contextEntry = _context.Entry<TEntity>(entity);
    if (contextEntry.State == EntityState.Dettached)
    {
        _context.Attach(entity);
    }
    contextEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Given the `BaseRepository` class containing this method, I created one `User` repository inheriting from this

```
public class UserRepository : BaseRepository<User>, IUserRepository
{
}
```

And I've used this in the PUT method of one Web API coded with ASP.NET Core

```
[HttpPut("~/api/users/{id}")]
public IActionResult Put(int id, [FromBody] User user)
{
    if (user == null || user.UserId != id)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    userRepository.Update(user);
    return new NoContentResult();
}
```

Now, when issuing a request, I get one error in the `_context.Attach(entity)` line. The exception says that it can't add the entity for tracking because there is already another entity with the same key being tracked.

When debugging I saw that `contextEntry.State` was set to `Unchanged`. Hence, it is *obviously* not equal to `EntityState.Dettached`. Still, the execution got inside the `if` statement and tried to attach the entity.

Something is quite wrong here. Is this a bug? Or am I doing something very wrong? I believe that I'm the one doing something very wrong with this update strategy, but I'm unsure about it. In that case, what is wrong with my approach?

**EDIT**: I updated the `Update` method to use just `_context.Update(entity)` and after `_context.SaveChanges()`. Still, the `_context.Update(entity)` throws one `InvalidOperationException` with this message:

> Additional information: The instance of entity type 'User' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked. When adding new entities, for most key types a unique temporary key value will be created if no key is set (i.e. if the key property is assigned the default value for its type). If you are explicitly setting key values for new entities, ensure they do not collide with existing entities or temporary values generated for other new entities. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached to the context.

Comment: Seems like somewhere in the same context are you fetching the same entity.

Comment: But in that case, the condition inside the `if` statement should return false, because the entity has already been fetched and is available in the context right? That `if` is there to protected against this possibility, I don't understand why it's not working as expected.

Comment: Is there are a reason why you’re not using `DbContext.Update` directly?

Comment: *“Still, the execution got inside the if statement”* – Are you sure that the error is caused from that line that you’re debugging? Maybe the `Update` method is called from another place as well? Did you check the full stack trace?

Comment: @poke, I've tried the `Update` method from the `DbContext` but it still issues the same error. I've added one edit with the full error message

Comment: Just for testing, could you just do that e tire update operation in a new context?

Comment: Check if you context is initialized twice ???

Comment: Okay, then what is the lifetime of your database context? What is the lifetime of your repository? How does the context get into the repository? Is `User` the entity used for authorization? Do you have any user-based checks for the route that could fetch the user from the database first?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting same entity from database some where in the project that's why it give you error.

In `Update` method you just add the entity in the context that's why you get `contextEntry.State` Unchanged.

You can fix this problem in two ways.

1. You need to call the `Detach` method on same entity when you get it from database.
2. copy the values from entity which you received in `Update` method to the existing context entity and save that entity in database.

Answer (score 0):

All the information is in the exception message... you already have another copy of the entity with that primary key attached.

I would recommend one of the following (preferred first):

1. Use a new Context for each action, don't have a long-lived repository/context
2. Use `.Set<TEntity>.Find(object[] key)` on your context using the Primary Key, in order to retrieve any entity you already have.
3. In your current update method, use the `Set<TEntity>.Local.Find(..)` to check if it already exists

Comment: Using a different context would mean that you lose the ability to see changes made to the Entity in question. In a Connected scenario that is not what EF Core is supposed to do. There must be a way to send an Updated Entity to the Context so that it and its children will have a proper state set.